# How to add the total number of dice roll outcome?

Tags: javascript, css

i am working on a dice roll game and i have found this virtually perfect JS based project for my needs. Pls have a look at the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Dice Roll</title>
    <style>
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
html {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(#545454, #454545, #676767);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.dice {
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(8rem, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  perspective: 600px;
}
.die-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  height: 6rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 6rem;
}
.even-roll {
  transition: transform 1.5s ease-out;
}
.odd-roll {
  transition: transform 1.25s ease-out;
}
.die-item {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  box-shadow: inset -0.35rem 0.35rem 0.75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    inset 0.5rem -0.25rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-template-areas:
    "one two three"
    "four five six"
    "seven eight nine";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}
.dot {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #676767;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset -0.15rem 0.15rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: block;
  height: 1.25rem;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 1.25rem;
}
.even-roll[data-roll="1"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="2"] {
  transform: rotateX(450deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="3"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(630deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="4"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(810deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="5"] {
  transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="6"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(900deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="1"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="2"] {
  transform: rotateX(-270deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="3"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-810deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="4"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-630deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="5"] {
  transform: rotateX(-450deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="6"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-900deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
[data-side="1"] {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="2"] {
  transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="3"] {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="4"] {
  transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="5"] {
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="6"] {
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 180deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="1"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: five;
}
[data-side="2"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="2"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: nine;
}
[data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: five;
}
[data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: nine;
}
[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: three;
}
[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: seven;
}
[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: nine;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: three;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: five;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: seven;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-area: nine;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: three;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: four;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: six;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-area: seven;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(6) {
  grid-area: nine;
}

button {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: none;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  justify-self: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .dice {
    perspective: 1300px;
  }
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="dice">
      <ol class="die-list even-roll" data-roll="1" id="die-1">
        <li class="die-item" data-side="1">
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="2">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="3">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="4">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="5">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="6">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
      </ol>
      <ol class="die-list odd-roll" data-roll="1" id="die-2">
        <li class="die-item" data-side="1">
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="2">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="3">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="4">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="5">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="6">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="roll-button">Roll Dice</button>
    <script>
    function rollDice() {
  const dice = [...document.querySelectorAll(".die-list")];
  dice.forEach(die => {
    toggleClasses(die);
    die.dataset.roll = getRandomNumber(1, 6);
  });
}

function toggleClasses(die) {
  die.classList.toggle("odd-roll");
  die.classList.toggle("even-roll");
}

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

document.getElementById("roll-button").addEventListener("click", rollDice);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a project run:

https://codesandbox.io/s/xjk3xqnprw

However, i want to add an additional functionality and want to print the total of the outcome of both die rolls. How can i achieve that?

Comment: please add code here

Answer (score 1):

Store the value of each die and add them up.

```js
function rollDice() {
  var total = 0;
  const dice = [...document.querySelectorAll(".die-list")];
  dice.forEach(die => {
    toggleClasses(die);
    var dieValue = getRandomNumber(1, 6);
    die.dataset.roll = dieValue;
    total+= dieValue;
  });
  console.log(total);
}
```

Comment: Use `parseInt(dieValue)`. Otherwise `total` will be treated as a string

Comment: Not sure if it will, `getRandomNumber` returns a Number anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got. Not sure if this is what you meant.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Dice Roll</title>
    <style>
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
html {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(#545454, #454545, #676767);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.dice {
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(8rem, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  perspective: 600px;
}
.die-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  height: 6rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 6rem;
}
.even-roll {
  transition: transform 1.5s ease-out;
}
.odd-roll {
  transition: transform 1.25s ease-out;
}
.die-item {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  box-shadow: inset -0.35rem 0.35rem 0.75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    inset 0.5rem -0.25rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-template-areas:
    "one two three"
    "four five six"
    "seven eight nine";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}
.dot {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #676767;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset -0.15rem 0.15rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: block;
  height: 1.25rem;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 1.25rem;
}
.even-roll[data-roll="1"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="2"] {
  transform: rotateX(450deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="3"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(630deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="4"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(810deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="5"] {
  transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="6"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(900deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="1"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="2"] {
  transform: rotateX(-270deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="3"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-810deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="4"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-630deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="5"] {
  transform: rotateX(-450deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="6"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-900deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
[data-side="1"] {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="2"] {
  transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="3"] {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="4"] {
  transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="5"] {
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="6"] {
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 180deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="1"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: five;
}
[data-side="2"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="2"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: nine;
}
[data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: five;
}
[data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: nine;
}
[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: three;
}
[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: seven;
}
[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: nine;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: three;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: five;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: seven;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-area: nine;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: three;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: four;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: six;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-area: seven;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(6) {
  grid-area: nine;
}

button {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: none;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  justify-self: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .dice {
    perspective: 1300px;
  }
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <p style="text-align: center" id="total"><p>
    <div class="dice">
      <ol class="die-list even-roll" data-roll="1" id="die-1">
        <li class="die-item" data-side="1">
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="2">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="3">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="4">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="5">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="6">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
      </ol>
      <ol class="die-list odd-roll" data-roll="1" id="die-2">
        <li class="die-item" data-side="1">
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="2">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="3">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="4">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="5">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="6">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="roll-button">Roll Dice</button>

    <script>
    function rollDice() {
     document.getElementById('total').innerHTML="Rolling";
    var sum=0;
  const dice = [...document.querySelectorAll(".die-list")];
  dice.forEach(die => {
    toggleClasses(die);
    die.dataset.roll = getRandomNumber(1, 6);
    sum+=parseInt(die.dataset.roll);
  });
  setTimeout(() => {
  let html=`Result: <span>${sum}</span>`;
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML=html;
  }, 1750)
}

function toggleClasses(die) {
  die.classList.toggle("odd-roll");
  die.classList.toggle("even-roll");
}

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

document.getElementById("roll-button").addEventListener("click", rollDice);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Huy, this is exactly what i was looking for. Although please can you tell me how to delay displaying the total until dice roll is complete as you might have seen with your solution the outcome is immediately displayed before the roll animation completes.

Comment: @SRahul I see what you are doing there. You can see the duration declared in `transition: transform 1.5s ease-out;` line. I editted the code, feel free to change the duration. If you have your answer, don't forget to mark your question answered